# Heuristic to detect geolocation spoofing

Tags: security, geolocation, heuristics, spoofing, anti-cheat

I want to prevent location spoofing on my app (Android and iPhone).
I understand once the device is rooted, there's nothing I can do to prevent GPS spoofing.

So I'm implementing a server-side verification.
Let's say I a list of the last 10 tuples (Location,Time) of the user.

What's the most efficient algorithm to detect if the user is spoofing the GPS?

Also, I'd rather have false negatives than false positives.

Comment: If you have a network connection you can use the IP address for additional geolocation information.

Comment: You could work out the average speed of the user and find whether it is above anything silly.